# Calculate sum of values in state with React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, calculator

I'm using React Hooks to store datas in the state.
I would like to create a function that calculate the sum of the values. I tried something but it is not working.

Here is my component with the function "totalIncome" :

```
import { UidContext } from "../components/AppContext"
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react"
import axios from "axios"

export default function Balance() {
    const uid = useContext(UidContext)
    const [userWalletIncomes, setUserWalletIncomes] = useState('')
    const [userWalletFees, setUserWalletFees] = useState('')
    const [formIncomes, setformIncomes] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (uid !== null) {
            axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}api/balance/${uid}`)
                .then((res) => {
                    setUserWalletIncomes(res.data[0].incomes)
                    setUserWalletFees(res.data[0].fees)
                })
        }
    }, [uid])

    const totalIncome = () => {
        Object.entries(userWalletIncomes).map(([key, value]) => {
            let total = 0
            console.log(value)
            for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                total += value[i]
            }
            return total
        })
    }

    return (
            <section className="border my-2 w-max md:w-11/12 mx-auto text-center">
                <h1 className="text-3xl my-5">Solde</h1>
                <div className="text-left mx-auto flex">
                    <p className="w-32 border p-1">Montant des revenus</p>
                    <p className="w-32 border p-1">{totalIncome()}</p>
                </div>
            </section>
    )
}
```

The console.log(value) returns :

```
1500 Balance.js:42 
640 Balance.js:42 
90 Balance.js:42 
1500 Balance.js:42 
640 Balance.js:42 
90 Balance.js:42
```

Any idea ?
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are close. You are logging the `value` and it's clearly not an array, so there is no `length` property and you can't iterate over it.

I would suggest using an `array.reduce` over the object's values and sum them with a computed total.

```
const totalIncome = () => {
  return Object.values(userWalletIncomes).reduce((total, value) => total + value, 0)
}
```

Other than this, you need to provide valid initial state for `userWalletIncomes`, i.e. it needs to be an object instead of an empty string. This is so the `totalIncome` function can work correctly with the initial state until the data is fetched and/or updated.

```
const [userWalletIncomes, setUserWalletIncomes] = useState({});
```

Comment: Hi. I can't set my state to an object, because if I do this, my API request won't push the data I receive from mongo to the state :/

Comment: @JohanBRAZILLIER Oops, forgot to return the result (oof). The second part makes no sense to me. You appear to already update it to an object, starting with an object just makes the initial renders work. Can you clarify your statement?

Comment: @DrewReese Dave found the solution :). But yes, I'm going to check if I can modify the way my state is set, it will be more logical. Thank you very much

Comment: @JohanBRAZILLIER IMO Dave's solution is sub-optimal, `forEach` is for iterating over an array and issuing a side-effect in a callback whereas the `reduce` is intended for reducing an array to a single value, the prototypical use-case ***is*** your exact question, computing a total. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: Ah ok I see. I passed my state to an object and it work with the .reduce ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

From what your logs are showing, I'd expect the function to work like this:

```
const totalIncome = () => {
    let total = 0
    Object.entries(userWalletIncomes).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        total += value
    })
    return total
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the forEach made a difference. But the result is 0. It should be 2230. It is like the forEach can't add each value. It stays at 0 :/

Comment: ah just realized value isn't an array, try like this

Comment: ok it's working now. I don't understand why, but thank you very much !